# Failure to reproduce GridSearch from sklearn in python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, grid-search

I am trying to do something similar to GridSearch in sklearn: I want to get a list of three models, where all parameters are fixed except for C corresponding to the 1, 10, and 100 in each model. I have the following two functions.

```
def params_GridSearch(dic_params):
    keys, values = dic_params.keys(), dic_params.values()
    lst_params = []
    for vs in itertools.product(*values):
        lst_params.append( {k:v for k,v in zip(keys,vs)} )
    return lst_params

def models_GridSearch(model, dic_params):
    models = [ model.set_params(**params) for params in params_GridSearch(dic_params) ]
    return models
```

I then build a model and specify a dictionary of parameters.

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
model = SVC()
dic = {'C': [1,10,100]}
```

And generate the models using the functions I just defined.

```
models = models_GridSearch(model, dic)
```

However, the outcome is the same model (using the last parameter, i.e. 100) being repeated 3 times. It seems there is some aliasing going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`model` refers to the same object throughout each iteration of the list comprehension in `model_GridSearch`, so you're just assigning a `C` value 3 times to the same object.  You can do a few different things to fix this: you could a copy of the object using the `copy` module, or pass in the class into the `models_GridSearch` function instead of an instance, and instantiate an object on each iteration.  You could also refactor your code in various ways to fix things.  It all depends on your goals.

**Copy method:**

```
import copy

def models_GridSearch(model, dic_params):
    models = [ copy.deepcopy(model).set_params(**params) for params in params_GridSearch(dic_params) ]
    return models
```

**Pass in class:**

```
def models_GridSearch(Model, dic_params):
    models = [ Model().set_params(**params) for params in params_GridSearch(dic_params) ]
    return models


from sklearn.svm import SVC
Model = SVC
dic = {'C': [1,10,100]}

models = models_GridSearch(Model, dic)
print models
```

Comment: Hi, only as additional information: I used `randomizedSearchCV` and doing `grid.predict()` is equivalent to do `grid.best_estimator_.predict()`. It is because sklearn assumes that when the `.best_estimator_` attribute es present then the model is trained. Otherwise it is not trained, so it is senseless predicting with it. Thus, `grid.predict()` instantiates directly to the `.best_estimator_` object. Really I don't know whether this logic takes place for `gridSearchCV` also.